# Correctly calling an instance method in a class

Tags: python, class, object, methods

The statement that returns self.seconds.splitSeconds() is not working correctly, so guide me with the proper syntax

```
class Time:
    def convertToSeconds(self):
      self.minutes = self.hours * 60 + self.minutes
      self.seconds = self.minutes * 60 + self.seconds
      return self.seconds

    def splitSeconds(seconds):
      self.hours = seconds // 3600
      self.minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
      self.seconds = seconds % 60
      return self

    def increment(self, seconds):
      self.seconds = self.convertToSeconds() + seconds
      return self.seconds.splitSeconds()

    def printTime(time):
      print(str(time.hours)+":"+str(time.minutes)+":"+str(time.seconds))

 time = Time()
 time.hours = 11
 time.minutes = 30
 time.seconds = 45

 seconds = 40

 time.increment(seconds)
 time.printTime()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add `self` as an attribute to `splitSeconds`.

```
def splitSeconds(self, seconds)
```

Additionally, your return statement should be

```
return self.splitSeconds(self.seconds) # edited based on comments
```

You should invoke the instance method on the *instance*, not anything else.

Comment: I got the solution the statement should be,  return self.splitSeconds(self.seconds)  and as you said def splitSeconds(self, seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You need `__init__` to initialize your `Time` Class, like:

```
class Time:
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes, seconds):
        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds

    def convertToSeconds(self):
      self.minutes = self.hours * 60 + self.minutes
      self.seconds = self.minutes * 60 + self.seconds
      return self.seconds

    def splitSeconds(self, seconds):
      self.hours = seconds // 3600
      self.minutes = (seconds % 3600) // 60
      self.seconds = seconds % 60


    def increment(self, seconds):
      self.seconds = self.convertToSeconds() + seconds
      return self.seconds

    def printTime(self):
      print(str(self.hours)+":"+str(self.minutes)+":"+str(self.seconds))

time = Time(11,30,45)

seconds = 40
time.increment(seconds)
time.printTime()
```

Comment: yet, I don't really figure out your `splitSeconds` function. Just copy your snippets. But, you can refer to it.

Comment: the splitSeconds method splits the seconds and generate a time(hours:minutes:seconds)